# Create a stacked ggplot2 bar chart with numbers in x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame from which I want to create a stacked bar chart with 1 and 2 in x-axis and while their values will be stacked and colored according to their values.

```
one=c(0.4,0.3)
two=c(0.4,0.5)
df=data.frame(one,two)
colnames(df) <- c("1", "2")

ggplot(df,aes(df[,1:2]))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack")
})
```

[image]

Also when Im trying to convert it to plotly I get ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df)  %>% 
   p1<-ggplot(aes(x = key, y = value, 
         fill = factor(value, levels = sort(unique(value))))) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity")
ggplotly(p1)
```

Comment: Try to use `gather` or `melt`

Comment: Is the graph what you're trying to achieve? What do the numbers in the different columns mean? What's in the x-axis? Please try to better explain your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
library(tidyverse);
stack(df) %>%
    ggplot(aes(ind, y = values, fill = as.factor(values))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: yes exactly but the colors range should be specified somehow like in the picture which goes from -2 to 2 by 1.

Comment: when im trying to convert itto plotly with ggplotly I get an error message:ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Comment: @firmo23 Your values do not go from -2 to 2 by 1. Values are `0.3`, `0.4` and `0.5`. Also you never mentioned `plotly`. Please do not add questions to your original post in comments. Let's work out a solution to the first part; then ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gather` from `tidyr` to reshape into 'long' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df)  %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = key, y = value, 
         fill = factor(value, levels = sort(unique(value))))) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: when im trying to convert itto plotly with ggplotly I get an error message:ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Comment: @firmo23  Please show your code by editing in your post